# Send Push Notifications to my app users

Tags: java, android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I've added the GCM services to my applications with help from [this guide](http://rmarcejaeger.com/2015/09/18/tutorial-how-to-implement-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-for-android-part-1-client-app/).

But now I want to create a new app, which I'll send the Push Notifications from. This app will be my Push Notifications sender.

My target is to send Push Notifications to all of the users of my applications. 
How would I accomplish that?

Do I have to use the Device Group Message or something else?

Is there any good tutorial of how to do this? I have no idea how to make it.

Answer (score 0):

GCM implements CCS which is XMPP endpoint to provide upstream messaging. You should have your own server to handle users and direct messages. Actually you need both downstream and upstream which is basically called chat. 
Take a look at the links for detailed instructions:

1. [Cloud Messaging / Send Upstream Messages](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/upstream#sample-send)
2. [GCM-XMPP Chat Tutorial](http://javapapers.com/android/android-chat-with-google-gcm-xmpp/)

Comment: I didn't mean chat. I just want to send Push Notifications to my app users. Like "Hey! We have new offers, you should open our app" - This specific message (its an example of course), will be sent by me to all my app users. Have you got my point?

Comment: I got your point but it requires both downstream and upstream to be able to send device to device. And it is same for a chat session you will just not allow users to send message messages will be controlled only by yourself(admin). Check the tutorials this is the only way via GCM!